# See if List only has certain values

Tags: python

Given a list:

```
x = [1,2,1,1,1,2,1]
```

Is there a one-liner to see if the list **only** contains the specified values and nothing else? For example:

```
x([1,2]) = True
x([1,]) = False
x([1,2,3]) = False
```

Comment: Why `True` for `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Because all of the items in `[1,2,1,1,1,2,1]` can be found in `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if, e.g., `set(x) <= set([1, 2])`.  (You can use `{1, 2}` for `set([1, 2])` in Python 2.7 and up.)

Comment: `set([1, 2, 3]).issuperset(x)` should be preferred then.

Comment: But then `set([1]) <= set([1, 2])` if `x=set([1])`

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to `set` suggested in other questions, which can be faster in some cases in which it fails:

```
all(y in (1, 2) for y in x)
```

It can sometimes be faster because `all` "fails fast" -- it bails out (doesn't keep looping) as soon as it finds one item that's false.

As for speed,

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'x=[1,2,1,1,1,2,1];check=(1,2)' 'all(y in check for y in x)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'x=[1,2,1,1,1,2,1];check=set((1,2))' 'all(y in check for y in x)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 usec per loop
```

(timing difference "in the noise").  The suggested use of sets per the other answers, if a killer bug present in the original versions of both is fixed, is indeed faster:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'x=[1,2,1,1,1,2,1];check=set((1,2))' 'set(x)<=check'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.425 usec per loop
```

The killer bug is that said original versions, for both answers (now corrected in edits), used `==` instead of `<=` -- so they checked that the items of `x` are exactly the same as those of `check`, rather than, as needed to satisfy your specs, being a **subset** thereof (one of your examples required `True` for `x` and `[1,2,3]` and both those original versions would have failed there).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to see if the elements of a list come from some set. If that's the case, you can convert to a set and use `issubset`:

```
>>> x = set([1,2,1,1,1,2,1])
>>> x.issubset([1,2])
True
>>> x.issubset([1])
False
>>> x.issubset([1,2,3])
True
```